# How can I set ping alerts using cloud watch in AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ping, autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to set ping alerts on an instance using `Cloud watch`. Is it possible or not ? I want this to be used in `Auto Scaling` feature, like if we can not ping an instance then another instance with same configuration should be launched automatically.

Any lead is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Autoscale doesn't have triggers for ping.  But what you can simply do is terminate the instance when ping doesn't respond.

Autoscale will automatically bring up another instance as long as it matches the minimum number of instances on the policy.

If you worry about traffic load for example, autoscale will bring up enough instances according to the cloudwatch metrics triggers that you have setup for the autoscale group.

Comment: Can you set up ping alerts with CloudWatch? How?